# CheckSum for a struct

Tags: c

```
UInt16 CheckSumUpdate (LOG_ENTRY_TYPE* pointer, UInt16 size)            
{
    UChar* data;    
    data = pointer;

    UInt16 chk = 0;
    while (size--)
    {
        chk += *data++;
    }
    return chk;
}

//message data structure typedef

typedef struct 
{
     TIMESTAMP_TYPE oTimeStamp;
     ASSERT_ID_TYPE ucAssertID;
     Int16 iData1;
     Int16 iData2;
     UInt16 uiChecksum;
}
LOG_ENTRY_TYPE;
```

TIMESTAMP_TYPE is a struct that has a 16 bit millisecond counter and 32 bit second counter and ASSERT_ID_TYPE is just an enum list of a bunch of things I want to check for when in operation.

So this kind of works but once the values become higher than 255 something bad is happening.  I know that an unsigned char (UChar) can represent numbers up to 255 but if I change UChar to UInt16 I don't get a correct answer either. Can someone point out my problem here?

Comment: "something bad" is no error-description. Neither does "dont get a correct answer" make sense. Answer from whom? What is "something bad"? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Each of the elements inside `LOG_ENTRY_TYPE` are most likely aligned to 4 or 8 bytes, and there is random stuff in the space in between. But .. what is the significance of "once the values become higher than 255"? All of your elements should be able to store a larger number than that.

Comment: I just want to add all the number up in that struct so when i send it off to an external eeprom i can verify it was sent correctly.  By something bad i meant the numbers are off, there is no error description.  And when i change to UIn16 i just get what seems to be a bunch of random numbers

Comment: Ok i may be wrong about the whole 255 thing that was just my guess.

Comment: you really shouldnt try to program hardware if you cant even do basic maths in code ... sorry but its like that. You are READING a STRUCT _BYTEWISE_ hence you WILL get also boundary-data which is highly dependent on your data-alignment. If you want to read & sum the FIELDS in your struct you simply need to reference them explicitly and add each one of them up one at a time - everything else is playful experimentation (which fails most of the time)

Comment: Additionally I am sure this is just a simple question for most of you so if you can just point me to some info I will try and figure it out for myself but as of now I couldnt really find anything

Comment: ok thanks specialist ill look into reading and summing the fields and referencing them explicitly.  If you have a bit of example code that would be great

Answer (score 0):

```
UInt32 chk = 0;
chk += data->iData1;
chk += data->iData2;
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)